# How can I retrieve my GitHub comments

Tags: github, comments, reply

I there a way to retrieve my GitHub comments?
I've posted some comments in many repository issues to asks questions, and I've found the answers by myself so I want to share my answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the GitHub API, you can get comments on [issues](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/comments/):

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/issues/:number/comments
```

You can use [GAPIGUI](https://www.gapigui.org/) to make API calls without coding.

Or if you just use the [search](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=commenter%3Adefunkt+type%3Aissue&type=Issues&ref=searchresults) feature using `type:issue` in the query, search for:

```
commenter:Ben type:issue
```

Comment: There is no end user interface to do that? It's really a missing feature. I don't want to spend time on the API, I just want to share my anwers as a end user. :(. BTW thank you for your reply.

Comment: Added the search query: "commenter:Ben type:issue"

Comment: Thank you! It's very helpfull!